# JSF final finally and finalize

Tags: java, jsf-2

I prepare myself for a job interview and I got a hint from my recrutiment agency that one of JSF questions can be
"What a difference between final, finally and finalize in Java Server Faces".

I have absolutelly no idea how this is related to JSF. I confirmed that this is about JSF. 
I worked with JSF profesionnaly but never met with such terms. It looks like someone messes Java (then this question makes a bit of sense) with JSF - OR I just simply miss some conception of JSF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a standard Java job interview question, and it is *"What is the difference between final, finally and finalize in Java?"* I'm confident that the recruiter just misquoted some other candidate.